# Put ONE piece of data in the center of Radial Bar Chart recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I want to put one piece of data in the center of rechart js radial barchart. I am a newbie when it comes to working on recharts.

Here is my boiler plate, all i know is that the location of the label should be placed "center"

[image: what the end result should look like]